# How to set MILESTONE null when build openjdk 7

Tags: makefile, java

Default build openjdk 7,target version is:

> Target Build Versions:
>
> JDK_VERSION = 1.7.0
>
> MILESTONE = internal
>
> RELEASE = 1.7.0-internal
>
> FULL_VERSION = 1.7.0-internal-senrsl_2015_01_22_20_38-b00
>
> BUILD_NUMBER = b00

but I will build version name this:

> RELEASE = 1.7.0

or this:

> RELEASE = 1.7.0_xx

I try

> export MILESTONE=''

or

> export MILESTONE=

or

> export MILESTONE=null

or

> export MILESTONE=""

but all can't generate version name : RELEASE = 1.7.0

what I will to do?

Answer (score 0):

set fcs is ok.....

file is in /home/senrsl/java/openjdk7u/make/README.pre-components

+27   MILESTONE             fcs, beta, internal or empty

build target version:

> senrsl@senrsl-ubuntu:~/java/openjdk7u$
>
> /home/senrsl/java/openjdk7u/build/j2sdk-image/bin/java -version
>
> openjdk version "1.7.0"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-senrsl_2015_01_23_10_39-b00)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b07, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

`configure --with-milestone=fcs --other arguments`

[image: pic]

Comment: Why did you insert the image? It's already in the code line.

Comment: @BuddyBob I'm not 100% sure that it was unintentional. There's a chance that it could have been inserted for emphasis or some other reason, in which case I think removing would have conflicted with the author's intent.